# Switching many threads using curl easy to single thread using curl multi

Tags: c, libcurl

I use [libcurl easy interface](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html) and I create lots of threads in my c++ app to handle these http requests. I would like to convert the code to use [libcurl multi](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) instead. Conceptually, the idea is clear: instead of calling blocking [curl_easy_perform](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html) on each curl easy handle from multiple threads I'll call a blocking [curl_multi_perform](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html) from a single thread and this call internally will handle all attached curl easy handles.

Things that aren't clear to me:

- how do I cancel any of the outstanding http requests that are being handled by the blocking curl_multi_perform call (from another thread). Similarly, would the same work with easy interface, can I end/about an http request from another thread while there is another thread does curl_easy_perform on that handle.
- Is it ok to add new easy handles to a multi handle while there is another thread calls curl_multi_perform on the multi handle?
- If I use [curl_multi_remove_handle](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_remove_handle.html) to abort one of outgoing http requests while it was loading data (let's say it was doing 1GB file download) then I can reuse the same handle right after that. Does curl close that tcp connection that was aborted in the middle? Otherwise, I don't see how that connection could possibly be reused without completely downloading entire 1GB body.

Is there a simple example that used to do multiple easy requests from different threads and same example converted to multi interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is really several questions disguised as one, which is not a good fit for stackoverflow.)

`curl_multi_perform()` doesn't block. It does as much as it can do for now, then it returns and expects the program to call it again when it's time or when there's activity on one of its sockets.

Ideally you can mark which transfers to stop in the other threads and as soon as `curl_multi_perform()` returns you can remove said easy handles from the multi handle and they're no longer in the game. Alternatively, you can use the individual transfer's callbacks (write/read/progress) to return error when you want that transfer to end.

It is *not* OK to use the same libcurl handle in more than one thread at any given moment. If you really need to use the same handle from more than one thread, then you need to do careful mutexing. See the [libcurl treading man page](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html). It is usually better to put things into qeueus from the other threads and let the single libcurl-using thread read handles or actions from that queue when it can, which then assures single thread access to the handles.

If you abort a transfer by removing the handle with `curl_multi_remove_handle()`, that transfer is aborted. Stopped. You can indeed reuse that handle immediately and if you just put it back in, it will be treated as a brand new transfer and unless you change any options in the easy handle it will simply start off from the beginning again with the same URL. Prematurely aborted transfers will of course be treated correctly, which might include closing the TCP connection if necessary.

Comment: after digging code, I came to the same conclusions, and implemented my code as a single thread that processes added/terminated http requests and loops url_multi_perform/wait